# Polynomial boundaries

Tags: polynomials

Suppose polynomial $P_n$ of degree $n$ is such that $|P_n(x)|\le 1$ for $|x|\le 1$. What can you say about the $|P_n'(x)|$ for $|x|\le 1$?

This question is just a generalization of this result: [$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ where $a, b, c \in R $ and $|f(x)|\leq 1$ on the interval $|x|\leq1$. Prove that $|f'(x)\leq4|$ on the same interval.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673232).

Comment: This seems like a special case of the Poincare-Sobolev Inequality, which I just learned for the first time. I'm looking into finding the constant for this specific case. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality

Comment: Unfortunately knowing that the bound guaranteed by the Poincare Inequality exists is usually what it is used for. Attempting to find the best Poincare-constant for a space is generally very difficult, and I am giving up now, but intriguing question!

Answer (score 1):

I vaguely recall this: among all polynomials with sup norm less than 1, the Chebyshev polynomials (or some shifted/scaled variant) are the ones with maximum first derivative. So, to get a tight bound, you just have to figure out the bound for derivatives of Chebyshev polynomials.

I'll try to find a reference, unless someone else finds one first.

**Confirmation**:
My memory was correct (surprisingly). There is a result known as the Markov-Bernstein inequality. Suppose we use $\|p\|$ to denote $\sup\{|p(x)| : x \in [-1,1] \}$. Then the result says that, for any polynomial $p$ of degree $n$, we have
$$
\|p^{(k)}\| \le \|T_n^{(k)}\| \cdot \|p\|
$$
where $T_n$ is the Chebyshev polynomial of degree $n$. The bound is tight, and is achieved if $p$ is the Chebyshev polynomial of degree $n$.

Figuring out explicit values for $\|T_n^{(k)}\|$ is straightforward. Putting $n=1$, we see that
$$
\|p\| \le 1  \Longrightarrow \|p'\| \le n^2
$$
which (happily) agrees with your result for the quadratic case.

Twelve different proofs of the general result are given in [this paper](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/na/people/Alexei/papers/markov.pdf).