# $f(x) \in C[-1,1]$ is a polynomial of degree n,and $|f(x)|\leqslant 1$,Prove:$|f'(x)|\leqslant n^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, inequality, polynomials

I met this problem ,But i don't know how to do it.

$f(x) \in C[-1,1]$ is a polynomial of degree n,and $|f(x)|\leqslant 1$,Prove:$|f'(x)|\leqslant n^2$

Let 
 $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$

and 
 $f'(x)=na_nx^{n-1}+(n-1)a_{n-1}x^{n-2}+\cdots+a_1$

But how to do next? Who can help me ! Thanks!

Comment: ["Markov brothers' inequality"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_brothers%27_inequality) might be a good keyword.

Comment: [Twelve Proofs of the Markov Inequality](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/na/people/Alexei/papers/markov.pdf)

Comment: @MartinR Did you mean [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673367/polynomial-boundaries)?

Comment: @A.G.: It seems that I confused things, I had *used* the inequality in an answer. – Yes, that is more or less the same question, and the answer has at least *a link* to a proof. I don't know if that counts as a duplicate if this question asks for a proof explicitly.

Comment: This is a consequence of the Markov-Bernstein inequality. See this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673367/polynomial-boundaries/673659#673659 The answer doesn't give a proof, but it tells you where to find twelve different proofs.